# How to wrap ProgressDialog in background thread with handler?

Tags: android, listview, youtube-api

I've adapted a Tutorial from [here](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/show-youtube-user-videos-in-a-listview/) to retrieve videos from a YouTube channel via JSON. Everything is working fine, but i wanted to add a ProgressDialog while the videos are loading in the background thread. I know how to add a ProgressDialog if the background thread is handled by AsyncTask, but i have no idea on how to do it in this case.

Heres the important part of the code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
    listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);

    getUserYouTubeFeed((VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView));
}

// This is the XML onClick listener to retreive a users video feed
public void getUserYouTubeFeed(View v){
    // We start a new task that does its work on its own thread
    // We pass in a handler that will be called when the task has finished
    // We also pass in the name of the user we are searching YouTube for
    new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "videoslusofona").run();
}

// This is the handler that receives the response when the YouTube task has finished
Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        populateListWithVideos(msg);
    };
};
```

So i have an activity that lists the videos on open, and on top of that i have a `android:onClick=getUserYouTubeFeed`in a button in the XML layout so the user can refresh if needed. The idea would be to put the ProgressDialog somewhere that it would be activated when the activity is started as well as when the user presses the refresh button.

If you'd be so kind to enlighten me as to where i should put the ProgressDialog, i would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Code for the entire activity with modifications suggested by Pratik Sharma:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.igestao.youtube.GetYouTubeUserVideosTask;
import com.example.igestao.R;
import com.example.igestao.youtube.Library;
import com.example.igestao.youtube.Video;
import com.example.igestao.youtube.VideoClickListener;
import com.example.igestao.youtube.VideosListView;

/**
 * The Activity can retrieve Videos for a specific username from YouTube</br>
 * It then displays them into a list including the Thumbnail preview and the title</br>
 * There is a reference to each video on YouTube as well but this isn't used in this      tutorial</br>
 * </br>
 * <b>Note<b/> orientation change isn't covered in this tutorial, you will want to     override
 * onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() when you come to this
 * </br>
 * @author paul.blundell
 */
public class MainVideoActivity extends Activity implements VideoClickListener {
// A reference to our list that will hold the video details
private VideosListView listView;
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainVideoActivity.this);

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
    listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);

    getUserYouTubeFeed((VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView));
}



// This is the XML onClick listener to retreive a users video feed
public void getUserYouTubeFeed(View v){
    // We start a new task that does its work on its own thread
    // We pass in a handler that will be called when the task has finished
    // We also pass in the name of the user we are searching YouTube for
    new VideosLoad().execute();
}

// This is the handler that receives the response when the YouTube task has finished
Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        populateListWithVideos(msg);
    };
};

/**
 * This method retrieves the Library of videos from the task and passes them to our ListView
 * @param msg
 */
private void populateListWithVideos(Message msg) {
    // Retreive the videos are task found from the data bundle sent back
    Library lib = (Library) msg.getData().get(GetYouTubeUserVideosTask.LIBRARY);
    // Because we have created a custom ListView we don't have to worry about setting the adapter in the activity
    // we can just call our custom method with the list of items we want to display
    listView.setVideos(lib.getVideos());
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // Make sure we null our handler when the activity has stopped
    // because who cares if we get a callback once the activity has stopped? not me!
    responseHandler = null;
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onVideoClicked(Video video) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(video.getUrl()));
    startActivity(intent);

}

private class VideosLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "videoslusofona").run();
        return "Executed";

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Carregando Videos");
        dialog.show();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: try with the solution I have posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So i finally got it, it looks like this:

The AsyncTask:

```
private class VideosLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{

private Context context;

public VideosLoad(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
 }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
   dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading", true);
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0){
    new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "videoslusofona").run();
    return "Executed";

}
```

Dismissing dialog at Handler:

```
Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    populateListWithVideos(msg);
};
};
```

And the onCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

listView = (VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView);
listView.setOnVideoClickListener(this);

getUserYouTubeFeed((VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView));

}



public void getUserYouTubeFeed(View v){

new VideosLoad(this).execute();

}
```

Thanks for the help [Pratik Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/556975/pratik-sharma)!

Comment: AsyncTask Deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(yourActivity.this);

        public void getUserYouTubeFeed(View v){
            new LongOperation().execute();
        }

        // This is the handler that receives the response when the YouTube task has finished
        Handler responseHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                if (Dialog.isShowing()) {
                    Dialog.dismiss();
                }
                populateListWithVideos(msg);
            };
        };
```

Declare this Asyc Task for this :

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            new GetYouTubeUserVideosTask(responseHandler, "videoslusofona").run();
            return "Executed";
        }      
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Dialog.setMessage("Loading");
            Dialog.show();
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and i get an error: `01-11 12:03:18.072: E/AndroidRuntime(1444): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.igestao/com.example.igestao.MainVideoActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()` I'll edit my original post with the whole activity as modified.

Comment: @jsfrocha take this declaration under onCreate() method `dialog = new ProgressDialog(LayoutTest.this);`.

Comment: @jsfrocha declare this only at top before onCreate() `ProgressDialog dialog;`.

Comment: with `ProgressDialog dialog;` before `onCreate()` and `dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainVideoActivity.this);` inside the `onCreate()` i get `01-11 12:57:14.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1549): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.igestao/com.example.igestao.MainVideoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 12:57:14.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-11 12:57:14.702: E/AndroidRuntime(1549):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)`

Comment: @jsfrocha you are getting `NullPointerException` at some point. something is not initialize and used.

Comment: The problem might be with `getUserYouTubeFeed((VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView));` in the `onCreate()` because if i take it off, it runs fine and when i click refresh, it displays the `ProgressDialog` and loads the videos. But the problem is i want to display them even before the refresh is clicked. That's what `getUserYouTubeFeed((VideosListView) findViewById(R.id.videosListView));` is doing in the `onCreate()`.. Any ideas on how to go around this ?

Comment: `01-11 13:08:11.890: E/AndroidRuntime(427): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 13:08:11.890: E/AndroidRuntime(427):  at com.example.igestao.MainVideoActivity$VideosLoad.onPreExecute(MainVideoActivity.java:61)` apparently it is caused by `new VideosLoad().execute();` but i can't see whats missing there.. aww

Comment: @jsfrocha its took more time I guess. If you dont mind then you can wrap up your required code and send that to me. I will digg more with that and send back to you.

Comment: sure, where can i send it to ?

Comment: Thanks for the help and availability, but i already solved the problem changing something in your code, ill post answer below. Thanks again mate.